# Recommended vertical refresh and horizontal sync rates for xorg?

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution

Are there recommended vertical refresh and horizontal sync rates to put in `xorg.conf` that will work universally? ie. will work no matter what monitor you have?

I previously intended to put random high rates as values, to cover all monitors, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea...

Comment: Does this include CRT monitors or only newer high definition monitors (i.e. 16:9 and 16:10 aspect ratios)?

Comment: @MGodby is there a difference?

Comment: Potentially, yes. Are you wanting to account for monitors with a resolution lower than 720p? The resolution isn't technically tied to the refresh rate, but the type of monitors that use 720p or higher will have different standards for refresh rate. Also, I don't think it would be helpful to specify a horizontal sync if you aren't using CRT.

Comment: @DevRobot, I didn't search much, but is it possible to put multiple monitor section, one for each monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such recommended value for sync rates. There is no way that Xorg know them dynamically only from monitor DDC data. Otherwise, you have to get a common frequency for monitors you have.

The fallback frequencies are: (`man xorg.conf`)

> **`HorizSync`  horizsync-range**
>
> gives the range(s) of horizontal sync frequencies supported by the monitor.  horizsync-range may  be  a  comma  separated  list of           either  discrete  values  or  ranges of values.  A range of values is two values separated by a dash.  By default the values are in units of kHz.  They may be specified in MHz or Hz if MHz or Hz is added to the end of the line.  The data given here is used by the Xorg  server to determine if video modes are within the specifications of the monitor.  This information should be available in the monitor's handbook.  **If this entry is omitted, a default range of 28-33kHz is used.**
>
> **`VertRefresh`  vertrefresh-range**
>
> gives the range(s) of vertical refresh frequencies supported by the monitor.  vertrefresh-range may be a comma  separated  list  of  either  discrete  values  or  ranges of values.  A range of values is two values separated by a dash.  By default the values are in units of Hz.  They may be specified in MHz or kHz if MHz or kHz is added to the end of the line.  The data given here  is  used  by the  Xorg server to determine if video modes are within the specifications of the monitor.  This information should be available in the monitor's handbook.  **If this entry is omitted, a default range of 43-72Hz is used.**

What seems a bad case for putting high frequency is when Xorg couldn't get DDC/EDID data correctly from a monitor that don't support those high resolutions. Then you have to go through recovery mode to fix it or run low graphic mode. If you have quite new hardware, I expect to be fine.

Comment: Would it be best to leave them empty then? Leave `xorg` to set the values?

Comment: Up to your experience and materials you are expecting. but best solution I could think of when dealing with bad hardware detection, set it high and add an script to fallback to safe resolution if you didn't click a confirmation message. Like the one in control center - displays.